# How can I see which user accounts are running which processes in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, process

I can look at the list of running processes/services by either going to Task Manager, or by typing `tasklist` in a console window. However, while both of these methods show me the list of running processes, neither one shows me which user account each process is running under. How can I see that information?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### How can I see which user accounts are running which processes?

**Solution 1 - Using the TaskManager**

Click on the `details` tab to see see processes and users.

> [image]

Source [Windows 8 Task Manager In-depth Review (Updated)](http://www.groovypost.com/review/new-run-windows-8-task-manager/)

---

**Solution 2 - Using tasklist**

Use the `/v` (Displays verbose task information) command line option:

```
tasklist /v
```

One of the output columns is "User Name".

Example output:

[image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) - TaskList displays all running applications and services with their Process ID (PID) This can be run on either a local or a remote computer.

Comment: Perfect. That little "v" to the rescue. Again. Thanks, David.